# Wrapper for 'python -m' command

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have a package with following structure:

```
my_package
 |-- src
 |    |-- __init.py__
 |    |-- __main.py__
 |    |-- foo.py
 |    |-- bar.py
 |-- setup.py
```

I'm trying to import foo and bar in **main.py** but it gives **ModuleNotFoundError** while executing with command ***python my_package*** from terminal but runs perfectly fine with the command ***python -m src*** from *my_package* directory. I want to exclude -m flag. All the material I found over the internet points to two things

- Set package location to sys.path.
- Set package location to PYTHONPATH variable.

I did these two things but none worked for me so far.

*Edit:* As suggested in the comments, wrapper is suitable solution for this. But I am unable to figure what logic goes there. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think you can run a Python *package* with a command that ignores its package status?

Comment: @DavisHerring as per my understanding of your question you are asking why I want to omit *m* flag from the command? It looks a bit messy or not user friendly.

Comment: But `python foo` has a meaning, and a different one.  If you want a pretty/short command line, wrap it in a shell script.

Comment: Isn't _python foo_ is simply used for executing foo script? And I know it can be done by using alias but the project I am working on has more than one contributors. So everyone has to do it on their own which seems quite unpleasant.

Comment: Yes, it’s for executing a **script**, which your package isn’t.  There’s nothing stopping you from putting a wrapper in the repository…

Comment: It will be helpful if you write a simple example wrapper or explain its behavior/base logic as an answer.

Comment: That wouldn’t answer this question as written.  Would you like to edit it to ask how to write a convenient wrapper for `python -m`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question.

Comment: OK.  Now that it’s the question, what sort of wrapper do you want?  A shell script (for which shell?), a Python script, or what?

Comment: Many thanks for the correction. As for the answer to your question python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard library has a module [`runpy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) for this purpose: make a script containing just

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module("my_package",alter_sys=True)
```

and then running bare `python` on *that* file will be equivalent to `python -m my_package`—including the requirement to set **`sys.path`** appropriately, either via `PYTHONPATH` or by placing the script in the directory containing `my_package`.